# Botões(Action) na notificação. Como saber qual foi clicado?

Tags: java, android, android-notification

A objetivo da notificação passa por mostrar uma questão ao utilizador, e este tem duas opções de resposta, "SIM" ou "NÃO".

O problema esta em saber em que botão o utilizador carregou.

Uma outra coisa que eu não pretendia mas que acontece, é que o utilizador é redirecionado para uma activity, e eu não queria isso.

Se ele carregar num dos botões é redirecionado para a "MainActivty", e o que eu pretendo apenas desta ação é que o mainActivity receba apenas uma informação qualquer sobre que botão o utilizador carregou, para assim fazer os registos necessários. A minha intenção é apenas que o utilizador responda à questão sem ser redirecionado para nada.

Deixo aqui o pedaço de código onde tudo isto acontece.
Espero ter sido o mais explicito possível, e gostava de saber se o que eu descrevi em cima é possivel de fazer.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ....
                    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 38);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent newintent = new Intent(this, Notification_Create.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, newintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
        }
    }

    public class Notification_Create extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int id = extras.getInt("id");

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            Intent intentTPC = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intentTPC.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                            0,
                            intentTPC,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                    );
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Organização: ")
                    .setContentText("Tu hoje vais à natação?")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_button);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_button,"Sim",resultPendingIntent);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_button,"Não",resultPendingIntent);
            mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Uma outra coisa que eu não pretendia mas que acontece, é que o utilizador é redirecionado para uma activity, e eu não queria isso.

Para isso o PendingIntent usado no método `setContentIntent()` deve ser criado assim:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  0, new Intent(), 0);
```

Para excluir a notificação ao ser clicada use `setAutoCancel(true)`.

> O problema está em saber em que botão o utilizador carregou.

Se quer que a cada botão corresponda um comportamento diferente crie um PendigIntent diferente para cada um:

Ao usar o método `addAction()` passe o PendingIntent correspondente a esse botão(Action).

```
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_button,"Sim",resultPendingIntentSim);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_button,"Não",resultPendingIntentNão);
```

> (...),para assim fazer os registos necessários. A minha intenção é apenas que o utilizador responda à questão sem ser redirecionado para nada.

Nesse caso o tratamento deve ser feito num serviço(eventualmente um IntentService).
Ao criar o PendingIntent use `getService()` em vez de `getActivity()`:

```
Intent intentSim = new Intent(context, SimService.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntentSim =
        PendingIntent.getService(context,
                0,
                intentSim,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );
```

Comment: obrigado, assim que puder testarei! @ramaral

Comment: Conseguiu implementar?

Comment: estou a testar a utilização do intentService que me sugeriu @ramaral

Comment: coloquei o que me sugeriu no mainActivity, aproveitei a classe Notification_Create, e extendi o IntentService...funcionou, a notificação apareceu...mas continuo na mesma com o problema, como faço o add action dos dois botões? Acho que interpretei mal o que me disse...é suposto invocar o service nos botões e não na main activity como fiz?

Comment: Você deve criar um IntentService para cada um dos botões. Nele deve colocar o código que quer que seja executado quando é clicado o respectivo botão.

Comment: criei um pending Intent com um IntentService para cada botão tal como sugeriu. Para testar se realmente funcionava meti um log.cat com um mensagem caso o utilizador carregasse no "sim" e nada acontece...o log.cat não aparece @ramaral

Comment: Declarou os IntentService no AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: sim declarei  <service android:name=".Notification.RegistoCanceladoService" /> <service android:name=".Notification.RegistoCriadoService" />  @ramaral

Comment: Não sei mais o que dizer. Se implementar de forma correcta aquilo que é indicado na resposta tem de funcionar. Só pode ser algo que esteja a fazer mal.